# The minimal ring which extends the semi-ring of natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers

That's the definition of integers given by Encyclopedia of Math. What does it mean for a ring to be minimal? How to show its uniqueness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, it means that if $\mathbb N\subseteq R$ in the sense that $R$ contains (a copy of) the natural numbers as a subsemiring, then $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb Z\subseteq R$: that is, there's a copy of the integers in $R$.

In other words, $\mathbb Z$ is the smallest ring generated by $\mathbb N$. Obviously by using additive inverses alone, the smallest ring containing $\mathbb N$ would have to contain $-\mathbb N\cup \mathbb N$ (I include $0$ in the natural numbers). Moreover, you can verify that $-\mathbb N\cup \mathbb N$ is an additive abelian group that is closed under multiplication, so it is a ring (the ring of integers.)

To convince yourself of uniqueness, you should just realize that there is no choice in the matter of how to extend $\mathbb N$. The $1\in \mathbb N$ is in every other (unital) subring, and by using addition alone you generate $-\mathbb N\cup\mathbb N$. You can formalize it by using this observation.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}\,∪\,\mathbb{N}$? Isn't it simply equal to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: There is a negative sign in front of  "$-\mathbb N\cup\mathbb N$" : so you take the set of integers and join it ("union") with the set of their opposites.

Comment: The set is unique, but what about the ring? The operations must be unique too, after all. How does the definition in the title imply two characteristic to the ring operations?

Comment: @asdasdfsss I don't follow your question... There is no need to "imply" the operations. They are dictated by the ring containing the copy of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @rschwieb Perhaps I'll put it this way: are they totally independent of the operations defined on $\mathbb{N}$, or are they defined using them, in similar vein to how $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined using $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @asdasdfsss Independent of the operations in $\mathbb N$? No, I wouldn't say that: the operations in $\mathbb N$ match the operations in $R$ by virtue of being a subsemiring, so they are part of what is dictating $\mathbb Z$'s multiplication. Without this compatibility there would be no relationship.

Comment: @rschwieb So, from what I understand, we have that for $(\mathbb{Z},+_{\mathbb{Z}},*_{\mathbb{Z}}$), ${\forall}n_1,n_2\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}:n_1+_{\mathbb{Z}}n_2=n_1+_{\mathbb{N}}n_2$, similarly for multiplication. How are addition and multiplication defined for non-natural members of integers? For the ring to be unique, there have to be unique (up to isomorphism at least) operations - two rings, on one of which $(-1)+_{\mathbb{Z}}(-1)=24$ and another, on which $(-1)+_{\mathbb{Z}}(-1)=(-2)$, wouldn't be equal after all.